# How to modify class's method behaviour? Python, class belongs to library that can't be changed

Tags: python-2.7, python-decorators

There is some library written on Python (2.x). Its code can't be changed. Inside of the lib there is class A. I need modify behaviour of A::method(). There are a lot of other classes: class B, class C and so on (they all belongs to the lib as well). They all uses class A in some way - no matter. All that means that I can't inherit class A and override the method A::method().

As I know - there is Python-Decorators-technic that should be used for it. But how exactly? Could you show some sample of such solution???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried:

```
from lib import A

def my_method(instance, *args, **kwargs):
    some_code_here()

A.method = my_method
```

Comment: After 10+ years of C++ it's little a bit difficult to think in way like this :)
Thanks!

Тhen I have another question - what is Decorator for?

Comment: Decorator is a function which modifies another function before returning it; it would probably also be a possible solution here, but decorators make sense if you need some modification done repeatedly, on various different functions.